# EF - WithOptional - Left Outer Join?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

With the following one-to-one models, both with navigation properties:-

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

*Foo* has an optional *Bar*.

*Bar* has a required *Foo*.

I have the following mapping on *Bar*:-

```
HasRequired(x => x.Foo)
      .WithOptional(x => x.Bar)
      .Map(x => x.MapKey("FooId"));
```

Which creates the foreign key on the *Bar* table named 'FooId'.

All this works fine, except it generates the sql for *Foo* with a 'Left Outer Join' to *Bar* on all queries when its not needed.

```
SELECT ..
[Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1]
FROM  [dbo].[Foo] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Bar] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[FooId]
```

Looking closer it only returns the Bar's Id.

[Searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413063/why-the-left-outer-join) stack I can see most suggestions to use `.WithMany` instead of `.WithOptional`, but I need the navigation properties.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you think about it, there's really no such thing as a 1:1, unless you are doing a shared primary key, because keys must be unique by their nature.  Sure, you can put a unique constraint on a 1:* to create an effective 1:1, but this is a sort of "virtual" 1:1 and not a real physical one.  EF does not support constraints like this, so it's not really possible.  This is why the join is there, because EF can only assume this is a 1:*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the standard behavior for one-to-one FK association and cannot be avoided. What EF does is to maintain internally a hidden (shadow) property like `int? BarId` for the `Foo` entity.

The only way to get rid of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s and keep bidirectional navigation properties is if you **can afford changing** the `Bar` db model (table) to use the (default EF one-to-one model) [Shared Primary Key Association](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations) by basically removing the `Map` call from the fluent configuration:

```
HasRequired(x => x.Foo)
    .WithOptional(x => x.Bar);
```

In this model the `Bar` table will not contain `FooId` FK column, but instead the PK column `Id` will no more be identity and will also serve as FK referencing `Foo` table.

This allows EF to not care maintaining a `BarId` in `Foo` since it knows that if there is corresponding `Bar`, it would be with `Id` same as `Foo.Id`.

If you can't change the database design, then you are out of luck - you have to either live with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s, or sacrifice the `Foo.Bar` navigation property and configure the relationship as unidirectional one-to-many as you already mentioned.