# EF code first - configure One-to-Zero-or-One relationship without shared PK/FK

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to establish a One-to-Zero-or-One relationship between two entities and I want the dependent entity to still contain its own Indentity column, instead of it being a shared key.

I want to do as much as possible following the conventions and not declaring explicitly anything that does not require explicit declaration (so, no **unnecessary** data annotations or fluent api clauses)

The entites:

```
public class File
{
    public int FileId {get;set;}
    //some omitted file properties
    public virtual Task Task {get;set;}
}

public class Task
{
    public int TaskId {get;set;}
    //some omitted task properties
    public int FileId {get;set;}
    public virtual File File  {get;set;}
}

 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<File>().HasOptional(f => f.Task).WithRequired(t => t.File);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

This creates a weird relation where the TaskId is both PK and FK column of the Tasks table. Which, I think means that it should have the same value as the file ID? (That is a question:) )

So, how do I make TaskId hold its own, sequential value and have FileId become a foreign key to the Files table?

Or maybe in case of 1-0..1 I should rather get rid of the TaskId property and make FileId the PK/FK property?

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bidirectional `one-to-one` relationship with explicit FK property is not supported.

So either continue using what you have now - [*Shared Primary Key association*](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations). Just get rid of one of the `TaskId` or `FileId` properties from `Task` and make the remaining a PK (EF will automatically use it as FK because that's the default EF `one-to-one` relationship model).

Or get rid of the `FieldId` property from `Task` and use the following fluent configuration (all is necessary):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<File>()
    .HasOptional(f => f.Task)
    .WithRequired(t => t.File)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("FileId"))
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

But I would recommend using the first approach (if there is no special reason of not doing it like existing database etc.) because it's better supported - the second includes some `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s in SQL queries as you can see from this post [EF - WithOptional - Left Outer Join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230950/ef-withoptional-left-outer-join/43281430#43281430).

Comment: Thank you very much, great answer:)